# how to pull all images from a hash field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have an Activity_Part model with a field called activity_json. this field is a hash that has a key named "image". I want to query/select only the ID of all Activity_Part only with activity_json field with key "image"

```
ActivityPart < ApplicationRecord {
               :id => :integer,
         :owner_id => :integer,
    :activity_type => :string,
    :activity_json => :json,
```

I thought of doing something like this:

```
x = ActivityPart.all
x.pluck(activity_json: 'image')
```

but I don't know how to return just the Activity ID with all the images in the activty_json field

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you're using postgres.

`jsonb` type has the `?` operator which can be used like this: `ActivityPart.where("activity_json ? 'image'")` as per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html).

If your column is of a `json` type then consider changing it to `jsonb`. You can alternatively cast it to `jsonb` in the query like so: `ActivityPart.where("activity_json::jsonb ? 'image'")` but be aware that this might negatively affect the performance of the query.